# How can I remove these parts of my filenames?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some files I need to rename in bulk.   For example:

```
Jul-0961_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz    
Jul-0967_S22_rep1_R1.fastq.gz  
Jul-0974_S32_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I need to remove the *S** part of the filename but I don't know the right regular regex to use.

Specifically:

```
Jul-0961_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz --> Jul-0961_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Something like, rename 's/*S**//' *.gz is what I'm looking for.

Is there a regex wizard out there who can show me the way?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the `S`s always followed by numbers or can there be letters too? Do you want to remove any of the underscores? Can there be any matching `S` anywhere else in the filename, such as if the prefix was for September?

Comment: Its always S then 1 or 2 numbers.  I need the one of the surrounding underscores to go as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are in the same format (i.e have the same number of underscores, you could use:

```
"ls" | awk -F_ '{ system("mv "$0" "$1"_"$3"_"$4) }'
```

Here we are using underscore as the delimiter and then building a command to execute with the system function

Comment: Yeah, you will need to pipe the output of ls through it, I have amended the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use something like this: `s/_S[0-9]+_/_/`

Comment: rename 's/_S[0-9]+_/_/' *gz  or rename 's/_S[0-9]+_/_/' _ *gz have no effect.  Perhaps I've done something wrong here.

Comment: The command `rename 's/_S[0-9]+_/_/' *gz` works for me with the test file names you gave. Remember `rename` issues no messages on success.

Comment: Do you have the usual Perl rename? What happens if you run the same command as `prename`?